# Trouble with Objective-C++ and Interface Builder

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, objective-c++

My view controller class utilizes an Objective-C++ class. I discovered that I must name it with an .mm extension for C++ imports/includes to work properly. However, I am using Interface Builder, and it does not want to play nicely with my view controller being a .mm file. I get compiler segmented errors. Any suggestions for such a use case?

Comment: specifically what kind of error(s)?

Comment: I think you need to show some code too.

Comment: In LLVM I get -> 
MyViewController.mm: internal compiler error: in pop_binding, at cp/name-lookup.c:410.    

In gcc 4.2 I get -> 
MyViewController.mm: internal compiler error: Bus error

Comment: I'm thinking the entire chain needs the .mm extension, not just the class that imports the actual C++.

Comment: The error I get is TextViewController.mm:464: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault

Comment: Akaru's suggestion worked like a charm for me - entire file chain included must be renamed to .mm

Answer (score 0):

First, as Akaru suggested in one of his comments: rename all implementataion files imported to the .mm (entire chain).

Another possibilities of compilation errors:

1. Make sure you do not use c++ reserved keywords as variable names. Example: I had **delete**  variable in renamed .m implementation file. I had to change it to **any_other_delete_varible_name** in .mm file. Most probably, variable names such as: `friend, delete, typeid` are the biggest suspects ;-)

Quote from: http://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_keywords.html:

> There are another **30 reserved words that were not in C, are
>   therefore new to C++**, and here they are:

```
asm         dynamic_cast  namespace  reinterpret_cast  try
bool        explicit      new        static_cast       typeid
catch       false         operator   template          typename
class       friend        private    this              using
const_cast  inline        public     throw             virtual
delete      mutable       protected  true              wchar_t
```

2 . C++ compiler is more strict about type casting (for example: I was getting error when trying to assign NSString to id type, etc...) Use  tricks to avoid it if there is a must: declaring **NSString** variable as **id** itself solved the problem.